# Laravel, filter timestamp by date only

Tags: php, laravel

I want to filter a table by user ID and the created_at field. The only thing is created_at is a timestamp, and I want to query by date only not time.

So something like -

```
$messages = Message::where(['from' => $fromUser->id, 'created_at' => 'TODAY'S DATE'])->get();
```

Comment: You can use raw methods and surround created_at with DATE(created_at) to just compare the date part

Comment: raw methods? do you have an example?

Comment: See my answer for an example :) Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you give me one example of your formatted date in your database?

Comment: timestamps in Laravel are formatted as: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I know (in Laravel) to compare a `DATE` against `created_at` is to use `whereRaw`, so for your example, you'd use something like:

```
Message::where(...)->whereRaw('DATE(created_at) = ?', [$today])->get();
```

You can find more information about Eloquent and it's other methods [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent)

Answer (score 20):

```
$query->whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'));
```

or

```
$query->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
```

Comment: This is a much better option then using whereRaw and should be the answer. Thanks Hamid!

Comment: Yes, in my case only Hamid's answer worked on the production server! Thank you